# GeoJSON from SQL View

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, postgresql, sql

I am trying to select database table features within a certain distance from a leafleat generated geosjon using an sql view in geoserver. I first used a GET function and a user here suggested POST. I am getting this error:

```
GeoJSON.js:221 
        
       Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at De (GeoJSON.js:221:9)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:117:15)
    at i.initialize (GeoJSON.js:92:9)
    at new i (Class.js:22:20)
    at Object.Ke (GeoJSON.js:439:9)
    at Object.success (app.js:289:29)
    at i (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28783)
    at A (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:14017)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:16305)
```

Edit: I updated the function that generates the path to create a geojson object from the l.geojson class then stringified it:

```
function getRoute_Nature(callback) {
    var url = `${geoserverUrl}/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=pgrouting:nature_path&outputformat=application/json&viewparams=source:${source};target:${target};`;
  
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      pathLayerNature = L.geoJSON(data, {
        style: {
            color: '#4CAF50',
            weight: 7,
            opacity: 1
        }
      }).addTo(map);

    natureGeoJSON = pathLayerNature.toGeoJSON();
    natureGjsonString = JSON.stringify(natureGeoJSON);

    console.log("geojson: " + natureGeoJSON);
    console.log("string: " + natureGjsonString);

    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
    });
}
```

The SQL view looks like this, not sure if my issue is in the SQL but looks like it should be working, path as a parameter, it will be the "stringified" geojson object:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(way)) AS geometry 
FROM (
  SELECT way FROM planet_osm_polygon 
  WHERE leisure = 'park' AND ST_DWithin(way::geography, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('%path%')::geography, 50)
) AS nature_features;
```

and the function I have right now using POST request is below, I am suspecting I have sonmething wrong here?:

```
function getNatureFeatures(path) {
// Create a new AJAX request to get the data from the server
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wfs",
  data: {
    service: "WFS",
    version: "1.0.0",
    request: "GetFeature",
    typeName: "nature_poi",
    outputFormat: "application/json",
    cql_filter: "INCLUDE",
    viewparams: "path:" + path
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Create a new geoJSON layer with the data returned from the server
    console.log(data)
    var natureLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
      }
    });
    // Add the layer to the map
    natureLayer.addTo(map);        
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
});
```

}

when I run the code, the console.log(data) returns an xml document error saying: (the number 25 changes depending on how big the path/input geojson is)

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException code="org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader"> 1 feature types requested, but found 25 view params specified. </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

This is how I use all the functions, after a button is clicked:

```
$('.nature').on('click', function() {
  clearAllInfo();
  clearAllLayers();
  getRoute_Nature(function() {
    calculatePathDetails(pathLayerNature, "natureInfo");
    getNatureFeatures(natureGjsonString);
  });
```

I get an error saying "Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.", I printed the stingified geojson from the getRoute_Nature function and it works fine, returns a valid geojson.

An example of an input geojson path would look like this (this is an example of natureGjsonString):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"nature_path.fid-29856ddd_186d1675796_-678e","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-75.691719,45.418201],[-75.691289,45.418379]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"seq":3,"id":110550,"name":"Cooper Street","distance":39.00298642840114}},{"type":"Feature","id":"nature_path.fid-29856ddd_186d1675796_-678d","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-75.691289,45.418379],[-75.691269,45.418387]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"seq":2,"id":112670,"name":"Cooper Street","distance":1.856382386068106}},{"type":"Feature","id":"nature_path.fid-29856ddd_186d1675796_-678c","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-75.691269,45.418387],[-75.691301,45.418424]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"seq":1,"id":368750,"name":null,"distance":4.825816521280108}}]}
```

Comment: Use a POST, not a GET, with the parameters wrapped inside the DATA block.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I just modified the post, thanks

Comment: @Vince Do you have an example of how to use POST? This is my first time working with this and I just followed examples and trying to make them work for my case.

Comment: A google on "How to use POST from JavaScript" should suffice. Your Question is about the SQL, but that's not the problem.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use a WPS process to do this, rather than a postgis view

Comment: I tried to make it work but couldn't find a way to pass the resulting geojson as input, also, I couldn't find a function that selects features within a distance and output them into a new layer

Comment: You are sending in a *FeatureCollection*; however `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` accepts only a single geometry - both logically, as well as structurally: it works on isolated GeoJSON *Geometry* objects only.  So a) your view/query expects a single geometric parameter only, and b) the GeoJSON syntax error is thrown by `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` because it can't parse *FeatureCollection*s.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a logical misconception in your approach, leading to the syntax issue:

- you are sending a *FeatureCollection* to the server to eventually get passed into the query - however, `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` parses *GeoJSON* ***`geometry`*** objects only (e.g. `path.features[i].geometry`), thus throwing `Invalid GeoJSON object`
- but you also send *multiple **features*** - `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` (and the whole approach in general, for that matter) is not capable of parsing more than **one** *GeoJSON* *`geometry`* object

---

With this in mind, you have three more obvious options directly on top of your approach above:

- isolate the one *feature* you actually want to lookup candidates for, e.g.:

  ```
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wfs",
  data: {
    service: "WFS",
    version: "1.0.0",
    request: "GetFeature",
    typeName: "nature_poi",
    outputFormat: "application/json",
    cql_filter: "INCLUDE",
    viewparams: "path:" + path.features[0].geometry  -- e.g. use the first feature of the selected
  },
  ...
  ```
- loop over all *features* in the selection and pull them in sequence, e.g.:

  ```
  for (const feature in path.features) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wfs",
      data: {
        service: "WFS",
        version: "1.0.0",
        request: "GetFeature",
        typeName: "nature_poi",
        outputFormat: "application/json",
        cql_filter: "INCLUDE",
        viewparams: "path:" + feature.geometry
    },
    success: function(sequential_results) {
      -- do something with the sequential results, like appending to a 'FeatureCollection'
    },
    ...
  }

  var natureLayer = L.geoJson(<combined_results>, {  -- pass in a merged GeoJSON object here
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
  });

  natureLayer.addTo(map);
  ```
- **merge** all selected *feature geometries* into a ***single** `Multi` geometry*, then send it in as one single *GeoJSON* *`geometry`* member as in option one - `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` is perfectly able to parse and process *`Multi`* geometries, or even a  *`GeometryCollection`*

Answer (score 0):

NB:  This answer was for an earlier edition of the question which was using GET rather than POST.  Therefore this answer is no longer relevant, due to edits to the question.

**OPTION 1**

Use an HTTP POST request instead of an HTTP GET request.  A POST request does not require the parameters to be included in the URL and therefore does not have the 2048 character limit of URLs.

POST requests are a little more complicated to generate, and if you need help with this, it may be suitable to ask an entirely new question about how to generate a POST request for Geoserver (or search for other answers here, or Google).

**OPTION 2**

Encode your JSON for URL compatibility before including it in a URL.  Eg,

`var pathString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pathGeoJSON));`

See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807180/how-to-escape-a-json-string-to-have-it-in-a-url

This will only work if the resulting URL (after encoding, etc) does not exceed 2048 characters, which means it will not work for complex GeoJSON features.

Also, for manually testing your URLs, you can use an interactive online JSON URL encoder, such as:  https://onlinejsontools.com/url-encode-json

Comment: Thanks, just edited my post with the new function and an example input geojson

Comment: OK, that makes this answer irrelevant, now that you're using POST instead of GET.  I'll update the answer to explain this.

Comment: I just updated my post to reflect the recent changed I made